# How to vary color of fill between listplots based on y-distance between them

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, filling

I have two lists with the same x-values but different y-values. I have used `ListPlot` to plot and fill the space (line) between them; however, I would like the color of the fill to be representative of the difference in y-values.

I have lists of the form `{{x1,y1},..}: a , b`

The normalized difference (from 0 to 1) between the points: `diff`

```
ListPlot[{a,b}, Filling -> {1-> {{2}, Map[Hue, diff]}}]
```

I have tried other methods, but this one was the simplest to demonstrate my intent.

I have had thoughts about `ColorFunction`, but my attempts have been met with frought.
The x-values are Real.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.se! In general, we encourage users to register as they can interact with the site more fully. In particular, you can upvote useful question and answers.

Comment: @rcollyer You're talking to a ghost :)

Comment: @belisarius where's my proton pack?!?

Comment: @rcollyer: who ya gonna call?

Comment: @J.M. I ain't afraid of no ghosts! :)

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 10;
{a, b} = {RandomReal[1, n], RandomReal[{1, 2}, n]};
t = Transpose@{Range@n, Transpose@{a, b}};
m = Max[EuclideanDistance @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]];
Framed@Column[{
   Show[ListLinePlot[{a, b}, PlotStyle -> Dashed], 
        Graphics[{Thick, {ColorData["DarkRainbow"][EuclideanDistance @@ #[[2]]/m], 
                  Line[Outer[List, {#[[1]]}, #[[2]]]]} & /@ t}]], 
   DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, m}, {y, 0, m/10}, ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"], 
              AspectRatio -> Automatic, FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
              PlotLabel -> "Distance Color"]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Another way:

```
f[x_] := {Sin[x], Cos[20 x]};
cm = First@NMaximize[Abs@Differences@f[x], x];
colorIdx[n_] := First@Abs[Differences@f[n]]/cm;
Plot[{f[x][[1]], f[x][[2]]}, {x, 0, Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["DarkRainbow"][colorIdx[x]]], 
     FillingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Going to 3D

```
n = 50;
a = N@Table[{Sin[t + Pi], Cos[t + Pi], (Sin[3 t] + 1/2)}, {t, Pi, 3 Pi, 2 Pi/n}];
b = N@Table[{Sin[t], Cos[t], (Sin[3 t] + 1/2)}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/n}];
t = Transpose@{a, b};
m = Max[EuclideanDistance @@@ Transpose[{a, b}]];
Framed@Column[{Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[t+Pi],Cos[t+Pi],Sin[3 t]+1/2},{Sin@t,Cos@t,Sin[3 t]+1/2}},{t,0,2 Pi}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[t], Cos[t], -1/2}, {Sin[t], Cos[t], 3/2}}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{r Sin[t], r Cos[t], -1/2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}, 
                 Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Black],

 Graphics3D[{Thick, {ColorData["DarkRainbow"][EuclideanDistance @@ #/m], Line[#]} & /@ t}], 
            Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
 DensityPlot[x, {x, 0, m}, {y, 0, m/10}, 
    ColorFunction -> ColorData["DarkRainbow"], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Distance Color"]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is not it somehow possible to do it from with in `ListPlot` option specification?

Comment: @PlatoManiac I guess not without manipulating the Plot's FullForm (which should be avoided if possible). But perhaps someone comes with an idea later.

Comment: I tried to use ColorFunction to define a field that was a function of x, and that had values corresponding to the difference.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** My favorite: **`CandleStickChart`**  -- easy, convenient and with a lot of cool options/features.

In particular, the last argument `#6` of the color function can be used to exactly what the OP wants. All one needs is to transform the input data to a form that `CandleStickChart` accepts: that is, a list `{{date},{prices}}` for each data point. This is easily done using `MapIndexed` as in the example below:

```
CandlestickChart[MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, Riffle[dt, dt] // Transpose],
  ChartElementFunction -> "ArrowCandlestick",
  ColorFunction -> Function[{date, open, high, low, close, trend}, Hue[trend]]]
```

[image]

---

Some test data:

```
ddd = RandomInteger[100, 10];
dt = {ddd,  ddd + (RandomChoice[RandomChoice[{-#, #}] & /@ Range[10, 25, 5]] & /@ Range[10])};
```

**Post-processing `ListPlot` output** to replace the `Line` primitive with appropriate directive/primitive combinations.

```
lstplt =ListPlot[dt,Filling -> {1 -> {2}},ImageSize->300,ColorFunctionScaling-> False];
{coords,lines} = {Cases[ lstplt,
  GraphicsComplex[crds:{x__},___] :> crds, {0, Infinity}][[1]],
 Cases[lstplt, ll : (Line[{_, _}] ..) :> ll, {0, Infinity}]};

Row[lstplt /. Line[{xx__}] :> {Thickness[.03], Opacity[.8], CapForm["Round"],
  #[Rescale[coords[[{xx}]][[2, 2]] - coords[[{xx}]][[1, 2]], 
      {Min@#, Max@#} &@(dt[[1]] -  dt[[2]]), {0.1, .9}]],
  Line[coords[[{xx}]]]} & /@ {Hue, ColorData["BrightBands"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Using `DiscretePlot`** and its options `ExtentSize`, `ExtentElementFunction`, and `ExtentMarkers`:

```
diff = Rescale[dt[[1]] - dt[[2]], {Min@#, Max@#} &@(dt[[1]] - dt[[2]]), {0.1, .9}];
g[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
    Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, RoundingRadius -> Offset[10]];

 sh1 = Show[DiscretePlot[{dt[[1]][[k]], dt[[2]][[k]]}, {k, Range[10]},ImageSize -> 300,
   ExtentSize -> .5, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["BrightBands"][diff[[Round[ x]]]]],
   ExtentElementFunction -> g],
 DiscretePlot[{dt[[1]][[k]], dt[[2]][[k]]}, {k, Range[10]}, Joined -> {True, True},
   PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> None, ImageSize -> 300]];

 sh2 = Show[DiscretePlot[{dt[[1]][[k]], dt[[2]][[k]]}, {k, Range[10]},ImageSize -> 300,
   ExtentElementFunction -> "ArrowRectangle", ExtentSize -> .5, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, ColorData["BrightBands"][diff[[Round[ x]]]]]],
 DiscretePlot[{dt[[1]][[k]], dt[[2]][[k]]}, {k, Range[10]}, Joined -> {True, True},
   PlotStyle -> Thick, Filling -> None, ImageSize -> 300]];

 Row[{sh1, sh2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome use of less well known charting functions, +1! Have you considered working something like this into a blog post (hint, hint!)?

Comment: Verbeia, thank you. My understanding of how these functions work is still too shallow and sparse to be able to put together a decent blog post (perhaps, as I continue exploring/experimenting, I may muster some courage :)